# Incremental values how to show one value at a time

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement, increment

I am making a simple sequence from randomly generated numbers. Each number will show an image linked to it.
for example,

the value 1 will show a picture of a cat. 
value 2 a dog 
and value 3 a mouse.

Each image has it's own dedicated imageview, the layout looks like this by  default, i.e image views that store black until it's number is called:

[image]

Each time the sequence increments. so on the second run two images will show, on the third 3 will show and so on.

The problem I am having is that all the images show at once. So for sequence one just the one image flashes (which is what I want). but on the second run both images show at once together instead of showing the first image then the second.

So to clarify let's say on the four runs the stored array is 1,2,3,3 I would want

image 1 to show, and disappear.then 
image 2 show and disappear. then 
image 3 show and disappear 
and then image 3 to show and disappear.

But what I actually get is on the fourth run 1,2&3 will show at once and disappear at the same time together. How can I break this up to achieve what I want. I have tried many methods and the same result happens. I can't get my head around this problem.

Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> stored_vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void Gen() {

    int i=0 ;

            Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(3)+ 1 ;       
        list.add(rndInt);
        int totalElements = list.size();
     Log.d("LOOK", Integer.toString(rndInt));
     Log.i("VALUE LIST ", list.toString()+" <<<<LIST HERE");        



    while(i < totalElements) {   

        retval =list.get(i);

     Log.d("RETVAL", Integer.toString(retval));
    String imgName = "flash" + retval;
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());

     if  (retval==1){                   

            Cat.setImageResource(id);
            Reset_View();
        }       
        else if (retval==2){            
            Dog.setImageResource(id);       
            Reset_View();
        }   
        else if (retval==3){
            Mouse.setImageResource(id); 
            Reset_View();
        }   

    i++;
    }

}
```

To try and delay the images showing at one at a time and to reset to it's default after showing for a few seconds I call Reset_View(); which is the following code:

```
    CountDownTimer  Reset_View = new CountDownTimer(1000 , 0010){ 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {              
        }
        public void onFinish() {    
            Centre.setImageResource(R.drawable.i1);
                upperRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i2);
                lowerRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.i3);
                lowerLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i4);
                upperLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.i5);  

             }
        };
```

So how can I achieve what I want. I have been stuck on this idea for weeks.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but does CountDownTimer run async? Ie. Does it prevent your for loop from just going on to the next one? If not, then it would make sense why all show up at once and disappear at once.

Comment: I added a high level answer. There are few ways you could do it, the first one that comes to mind, I tried to explain.

Comment: How did this code even compile? Did you mess it up while pasting it or something? Because there is no way this didn't produce a ton of syntax errors.

Comment: The code does work, I'll have a read through and see if the paste messed stuff up. It definitely does run with no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a high level idea of what you could do.

Put all the showing and hiding in the countdowntimer. So basically you would need to handle the 'onTick' and hide or show the images when needed. Something like 'time > 0 and < 1000' hide all but the first image. 1000 to 2000, show only second image. 2000 to 3000, show only third image. On finish, hide all.

When you instantiate the timer after the for loop, if retval is 1 - then 1000 would be how long to run, retval = 2, then 2000, retval = 3, then 3000.

There is probably a better way to do it but this is the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that `Reset_View();` is not a method. The line even states `public CLASS Reset_View(); extends CountDownTimer`. ( I don't know ho that can be a valid class name but whatever) Therefore, calling `Reset_View();` will not actually do anything. 
You need to change the name of the class to something else, I suggest `ResetTimer`. Then to reset the Views you must create an instance of `ResetTimer` and use its `start()` method like this:

```
new ResetTimer(1000, 1000).start();
```

Note: the first number in the constructor is the total time (in milliseconds) until the timers `onFinish()` is called. The second one it the time between the `onTick()`s. Since you don't use this method, the number you put in there doesn't matter.